# Validating XML String in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

Please note that I am very new to .NET and ASP.NET.

I have a script that attempts to load XML text from a URL and I am having difficulty figuring out how to check to see if it is valid, normalized XML. I don't have a schema as there are several variables which could change the XML format, I just want to check to make sure all of the opening tags are closed properly so I can verify that the entire string loaded properly. Here is what I have right now.

```
Dim objResponse As HttpWebResponse
Dim objRequest As HttpWebRequest
Dim strXml As String
Dim newMembers As New DataSet
Dim xmlReader As StringReader

'get xml from current file
objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(xmlurl)
objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse()

Using sr As New StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream())
    strXml = sr.ReadToEnd()
    sr.Close()
End Using

'I would like to add something here to validate strXML

' create a dataset from the XML file pulled down from the remote server
newMembers = New DataSet()
xmlReader = New System.IO.StringReader(strXml)
newMembers.ReadXml(xmlReader)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the XmlDocument.Load method and if it fails, you can assume it's not valid XML.

[XmlDocument.Load Method (Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e48zttz7.aspx)

Comment: Thanks - I just added a bit more code so people could see how it was being consumed. Should the DataSet method ReadXML do the same thing?

Comment: @unclesol - I believe so. ReadXml should fail if the source is invalid XML.

Answer (score 3):

```
dim x = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse("<xml><valid_tag /></xml>")
```

if your xml is not valid, an exception is thrown.

Or else:

```
dim x = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load("path_to_xml_file")
```

Same behavior

Answer (score 1):

Create an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5awd922.aspx) object, and call the [LoadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) method on it. If the tags aren't correctly constructed, it will throw an exception.

```
Dim xDoc As New XmlDocument()
xDoc.LoadXml(strXml)
```