# How to validate XML against Schema in VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd

I am trying to validate xml against a schema. I am using XmlReaderSetting and trying to follow an example on MSDN but not able to make it work. It doesn't validate the xml even I throw a totally different file against schema. Can anyone explain me what I am missing?

Thanks,

```
    Protected Sub ValidateXML(xmlFilePath As String, schemasFilePath As String)

    Try

        Dim settings As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings()

        settings.Schemas.Add("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", schemasFilePath)
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema

        Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilePath, settings)
        Dim document As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        document.Load(reader)

        Dim eventHandler As ValidationEventHandler = New ValidationEventHandler(AddressOf ValidationEventHandler)

        ' the following call to Validate succeeds.
        document.Validate(eventHandler)
        reader.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Messagebox(ex.Message, "error")
    End Try

End Sub

Protected Sub ValidationEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ValidationEventArgs)

    Select Case e.Severity
        Case XmlSeverityType.Error
            'Messagebox(e, "error")
        Case XmlSeverityType.Warning
            'Messagebox(e, "error")
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the `ValidationEventHandler` method get called?

Comment: See already asked queries please refer [this][1] example


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595875/validating-xml-string-in-vb-net

Comment: Hi Steven, ValidationEventHandler method doesn't ever get called .. tHANKS. ANY CLUE?

Comment: Hi Sandy, I have checked the question you posted .. it's not relevant .. it's not using a schema so I can't use that post .. thanks ..

Comment: You will receive notifications whenever any comment is added to your own question, but others like @sandy and I will not.  If you want someone else to be notified, you need to put the @ sign followed by their name.

Comment: Thanks @StevenDoggart .. I didn't know that before ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing two different ways to read the XML file.  You are using an `XmlReader` object and an `XmlDocument` object.  Typically, you'd only use one or the other.  It will work to use both, as you have done, but it does introduce some unnecessary confusion.

The reason the validation is not working is because you are adding the schema validation to the reader, but then you attach the `ValidationEventHandler` method to the `XmlDocument` object.  Both `XmlDocument` and `XmlReader` are capable of performing schema validation, and they each have their own `XmlSchemaSet` and validation event handler that they use to perform the the validation.  You have given half of what they need to each of them instead of all of what they need to one or the other.  In other words, you have done the following:

- XmlReader's Schema: **SET**
- XmlReader's Event Handler: **NOT SET**
- XmlDocument's Schema: **NOT SET**
- XmlDocument's Event Handler: **SET**

As such, neither object has all the information it needs to properly validate.  The `XmlReader` object will be performing the validation, but you won't be notified of any of the errors that it finds, whereas the `XmlDocument` object will not be doing any validation at all, but does have the capability to notify you, in the event that it did find any validation errors.  To fix it, you need to either set the `XmlReader` object's validation event handler, or you need to set the `XmlDocument` object's schema.  For instance:

```
Dim settings As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings()
settings.Schemas.Add("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", schemasFilePath)
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
AddHandler settings.ValidationEventHandler, New ValidationEventHandler(AddressOf ValidationEventHandler)
Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilePath, settings)
' Read the document...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Steven, it is really good .. But I am still trying to take in all .. so if I set eventHandler to XMLReaderSettings, do I still do document.Validate(eventHandler)? Do I still need to set eventHandler to Document as well?

Comment: If you are using `XmlReader` to do your validation, then you don't need to use `XmlDocument` at all.  You just need to loop through reading the whole document until you hit the end.  If you want to use the `XmlDocument` object in combination with the `XmlReader`, it will do exactly that for you when you call `Load`.  So, in that case, there is no reason to call the `Validate` method.

Answer (score 0):

It is not calling the Event Handler:

```
Protected Sub ValidationEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ValidationEventArgs)

    Select Case e.Severity
        Case XmlSeverityType.Error
            'Messagebox(e, "error")
        Case XmlSeverityType.Warning
            'Messagebox(e, "error")
    End Select

End Sub
```