# Error Handling in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have created a SSIS package which gets the XML file from a folder and checks with the schema, if the schema fails, the package logs the error and moves the file to a error folder. Currently, I have done all the requirements, and is working fine except the error message i'm getting at the end of the execution.

1. Validate XML file

[image]

2. The error message which I'm getting

[image]

3. The error message which I'm getting

[image]

The package works fine as expected. How can I suppress this error message?

**Update #1:**

This is my error history

[image]

This is my XML Schema validation task properties.

[image]

Comment: What is the error message you receive from package execution? I.e. what error message do you see if you check the execution log at Visual Studio?

Comment: How to supress the error might depend on how severe the error is. You've shown us screenshots of the error happening in Visual studio Once it has run and the error has happened, before you press Stop Debugging, go to the 'Progress' tab and scroll down tofind the error message you're getting. (Note- you could set 'fail package on failure' on the task to 'false' in its properties, but there might be other solutions hence not putting as an answer yet).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Suggestions

The issue may be caused by the `FailPackageOnFailure` and `FailParentOnFailure` properties. Click on the `Validate XML` Task and in the Properties Tab change these properties values. Alos in the `Control Flow` Go to the properties and change the `MaximumErrorCount` value and make it bigger than `1`.

[image]

Also you can find other helpful informations in this link:

- [Continue Package Execution After Error In SSIS](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2013/08/05/continue-package-execution-after-error-in-ssis/)

## Workaround using Script Task

1. Add 3 Variables to your package:

   ```
   @[User::XmlPath] Type: String, Description: Store the Xml File Path
   @[User:XsdPath] Type: String, Description: Store the Xsd File Path
   @[User:IsValidated] Type: Boolean, Description: Store the result of Xml validation
   ```
2. Add a script Task, select `XmlPath` and `User:XsdPath` as ReadOnly Variables and `IsValidated` As ReadWrite Variable
3. Set the Script Language to `Visual Basic`
4. In the Script Editor write the following code *(this is the whole script task code)*

   ```
   #Region "Imports"
   Imports System
   Imports System.Collections.Generic
   Imports System.Data
   Imports System.Math
   Imports System.Text
   Imports System.Xml
   Imports System.Xml.Schema
   Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
   #End Region

   <Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute()>
   <System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)>
   Partial Public Class ScriptMain
       Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase

       Enum ScriptResults
           Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
           Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
       End Enum

       Public Function LoadXml(xmlFilePath As String, xsdFilePath As String) As Boolean
           Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings()
           settings.Schemas.Add(Nothing, xsdFilePath)
           settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
           Dim errorBuilder As New XmlValidationErrorBuilder()
           AddHandler settings.ValidationEventHandler, New ValidationEventHandler(AddressOf errorBuilder.ValidationEventHandler)
           Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilePath, settings)
           ' Read the document...
           Dim errorsText As String = errorBuilder.GetErrors()
           If errorsText IsNot Nothing Then
               Return False
           Else
               Return True
           End If
       End Function

       Public Sub Main()

           Dts.Variables("IsValidated").Value = LoadXml(Dts.Variables("XmlPath").Value.ToString, Dts.Variables("XsdPath").Value.ToString)

           Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
       End Sub


   End Class

   Public Class XmlValidationErrorBuilder
       Private _errors As New List(Of ValidationEventArgs)()

       Public Sub ValidationEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As ValidationEventArgs)
           If args.Severity = XmlSeverityType.Error Then
               _errors.Add(args)
           End If
       End Sub

       Public Function GetErrors() As String
           If _errors.Count <> 0 Then
               Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
               builder.Append("The following ")
               builder.Append(_errors.Count.ToString())
               builder.AppendLine(" error(s) were found while validating the XML document against the XSD:")
               For Each i As ValidationEventArgs In _errors
                   builder.Append("* ")
                   builder.AppendLine(i.Message)
               Next
               Return builder.ToString()
           Else
               Return Nothing
           End If
       End Function
   End Class
   ```
5. Use Precedence Constraints with expression to manipulate both of Validation success and failure cases

[image]

[image]

**Script Code Reference**

- [VB.NET validating XML file against XSD file and parsing through the xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467389/vb-net-validating-xml-file-against-xsd-file-and-parsing-through-the-xml)

Comment: I did all that, It's working fine, the package is not crashing, and tends to work continuously. The only thing is, i'm getting this error message. Since I have handled the xml schema error as shown in the first image I don't want the error message (image 3) after executing the package. That's what I need

Comment: You cannot remove it in this case  you can use `ForceExecutionResult` but i doesn't help in this case

Comment: You can use a script task to validate Xml, and assign the result to a variable, then use precedence expressions to achieve a similar case

Comment: @RanjithVaradan Also be aware that if you stop showing error messages from tasks, other error will be ignored, which is very critical

Comment: Is it possible to keep the xml schema validation result in a boolean variable and then force this task result to success then process the error file using the boolean variable in the expression?

Comment: I think you need a script task

Comment: @RanjithVaradan check my answer update, note that the code i used is copied from the link mentioned in the references, i really couldn't test it , plz give me a reply when testing it